# Windows cannot find .bat. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have no idea when this started to happen but it is preventing me from opening .bat files on double click. I am only able to run it as administrator. Is there anyway to fix this so i can double click instead of running as administrator? This causes some programs not to work.

I've tried to reset the file association in the registry, checked the environment variables, and I checked to see if cmd was actually in the System32 folder.

If more info is needed, I will try to provide it.

Comment: You need to show us a screenshot of what happens in a Command Prompt window, and also the file association registry entries.

Comment: Here is an image of the error. https://i.imgur.com/789l25n.png

Comment: You might try first from command line run `FTYPE batfile="%1" %*` and then run `ASSOC .bat=batfile`, and see if that helps. If not, then from an admin elevated command prompt, type in `sfc /scannow` and press Enter. Let that complete, reboot the PC, and then try again.

Comment: Apart from the advice by @PimpJuiceIT, I notice that the `.bat` file is on the desktop. Try to copy it to some folder and start it from there. This might be a matter of permissions.

Comment: I tried what pimp juice and harrymc said but i still cannot open the bat file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, some of you might think I'm stupid but this is how I solved this issue.

I went into my environment variables and was looking for COMSPEC but instead I found ComSpec. Once I renamed it back to COMSPEC everything started working again.

I have no idea how it was even renamed in the first place but that fixed my issue.

Hope this helps other people with this issue.

Comment: Environmental variables are not case sensitive.  My compsec variable is in camel case and works just fine. `ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`

Comment: If this change fixed it for you, it suggests that the problem was a hiccup, and not reproducible.

Comment: How in the world that works out :P I was running into Flutter setup error and this helped me out after long hours of struggling. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to cmd, not to your specific bat file.
so open cmd (start menu >> RUN >> type **cmd** and press ENTER)
on the task bar, right click on the cmd icon, you will see a small menu, right click on the first option in is ( **Command Prompt** )... now choose **Properties** , then in **Shortcut** tab press **Advanced**, then check **Run As Administrator**
then press **OK** and **OK**
try now to run your bat file...

please comment if this did not solve your case... otherwise vote my answer as a solution...

Comment: This did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanx to Squashman above (can't vote his reply as an answer), my ComSpec value was changed somehow to c:\PHP, reset it to the following as per Squashman and fixed (posting this since some might miss his reply to an answer):

Right click "This PC" > Properties > Advanced System Settings > "Environment Variables..." > in System Variables make sure you have ComSpec (or COMSPEC but shouldn't matter) and it's set as follows:

Variable: ComSpec

Value: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: I do not see Squashman, above. Are you perhaps posting in the wrong question?

Comment: He commented on the above posted (currently chosen/voted) answer on Nov  29 '18.  You should see it as a comment/reply below the original poster's answer posted above.